# Calendar in squarespace

Tags: html, calendar, squarespace

I am setting up a square space and I want to use the calendar they have but I want to put it in my own div instead. Does anyone know how I can get the code to manually add the calendar. If that doesn't work is there another better calendar I can embed? I was thinking of maybe trying the google calendar but I am not sure. Any help or suggestions? I just want to see a small Month calendar

Comment: post some codes... what all have you tried till now.

Comment: Well I added my own div to the front page so I can do more stuff with it, but I cant get the calendar. I dont have any code for a calendar yet, thats why I am confussed. How can I get the code, I tried adding the calendar block underneath my divs and view page -> view page source, and I see something like this:

Comment: <div class="row sqs-row"><div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12"><div class="sqs-block calendar-block" data-block-json="&#123;&#125;" data-block-type="26" id="block-f2fd66cb1ffba23e81f6"><div class="sqs-block-content"><!-- The calendar block is initialized by javascript. --></div></div></div></div>

Comment: but surely that cant be it can it? Seems so little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery plugin here called 'jquery.ui.datepicker.js'. download basic jquery and this js and use it as below. suppose your div id is 'selectDate'

```
jQuery("#selectDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        showOn: "both",
        buttonText: "Calendar",
        minDate: currentDate,
        maxDate: lastDate,
        buttonImage:"calendar.png", // add your datepicker image
        closeText: 'X',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

refer more details on http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/